# Print Modification Date with a Bash

Tags: bash, date

I'm having some trouble getting a bash script to print the modification date of a file, this is my code:

```
files=$(ls -R)    

for file in ${files}
do
  modification=$(date +%D -r ${file})
    echo ${modification}
done
```

The problem is that when I run the script everything on the same level as the script gets its date printed but if the file is one level below or more I get an error as you can see in the following output:

```
File .: was modified on 
File 1.txt was modified on 02/05/19
File 2.txt was modified on 02/05/19
File 3.txt was modified on 02/05/19
File folder was modified on 02/05/19
File GetFiles.sh was modified on 02/05/19
date: ./folder:: No such file or directory
File ./folder: was modified on 
date: folder1.txt: No such file or directory
File folder1.txt was modified on 
date: folder2.txt: No such file or directory
File folder2.txt was modified on 
date: folder3.txt: No such file or directory
File folder3.txt was modified on
```

Comment: What specifically is the question? Are you asking why you can't use just `folder1.txt` to refer to a file that exists in a subdirectory?

Comment: I guess the specific question would be why can't I print the dates of the files on sub folders?

Comment: `ls -R` is going to have more in it than just file names, i.e., subfolder headings. So your `for file in ${files}` is going to try to operate on these subdirectory headings.

Comment: Ok so should I use `find`? I'm asking because if I comment the `modification=$(date +%D -r ${file})` line and just print the file name it works so that's why I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **; do date +"$i was modified on %D" -r "$i"; done
```

From `man bash`:

> `globstar`:
>                         If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and  zero  or
>                         more  directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and
>                         subdirectories match.

---

See: `help shopt`

Comment: 20+ years of bash and I'd never played with the `help` builtin.... There are still some nuggets yet discovered.